# How to invoke method/constructor parameter hint in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-hinting

If I write code sequentially, then after I enter some method call and opening parenthesis, I get a hint after delay:

[image]

if I discard it or return to the place later, I see no any hint:

[image]

How to invoke it without retyping the code?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will give you a pop-up with the method parameters. Usefully, the parameter corresponding to your cursor position will be highlighted and will change as you move back and forth through the parameters.

Intellij provides a lot of assistance. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_assistance.html) for a summary of what's available.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same condition in the earlier days.
No need to retype the complete code but just retype the comma(,) intellij is intelligent enough to guess the next variable value and suggest you better. I used this many times so far and made me to save my time in all instances.
Hope i was useful.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac the shortcut is <kbd>⌘ (Command)</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
It works fine.